# IDA kernel debugging Error

Tags: debugging, kernel, ida

Environment:

> Windows 7 64-bit version
>
> Virtual machine (Vmware 8) + Virtualkd: Windows XP 32-bit version

Trying to debug the kernl with `ida 6.1`, I get this error:

```
Windbg: using debugging tools from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Debugging Tools for Windows (x86)\'
Connecting to the kernel with 'com:port=\\.\pipe\kd_WinXP_kerneldbg'
**Connect failed: Incorrect function.**
Flushing buffers, please wait...ok
Unloading IDP module C:\ida61\procs\pc.w32...
```

`vmmon64` looks ok:

```
http://s13.postimg.org/qpn50bcdz/Untitled.png
```

Connection string on `IDA`:

```
com:port=\\.\pipe\kd_WinXP_kerneldbg
```

anyone please

Comment: How does vm [configure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff538143(v=vs.85).aspx)?

Comment: I follow this tut: http://www.hexblog.com/?p=123

Comment: check vm settings with `bcdedit /dbgsettings` command

Answer (score 3):

The connection string is you've used is when you have a physical serial port connection.  For a virtual machine, you need to use a slightly different string.  Try:

```
com:pipe,port=\\.\pipe\kd_WinXP_kerneldbg
```

Notice the extra `pipe,port` section required for virtual machine COM connections.  Here are the possible connection strings, referenced from [Live Kernel-Mode Debugging Using WinDbg](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh451166%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
windbg [-y SymbolPath] -k net:port=PortNumber,key=Key
windbg [-y SymbolPath] -k 1394:channel=1394Channel[,symlink=1394Protocol] 
windbg [-y SymbolPath] -k usb:targetname=USBString
windbg [-y SymbolPath] -k com:port=ComPort,baud=BaudRate
windbg [-y SymbolPath] -k com:pipe,port=\\VMHost\pipe\PipeName[,resets=0][,reconnect]
windbg [-y SymbolPath] -k com:modem
windbg [-y SymbolPath] -kl 
windbg [-y SymbolPath] -k
```

In the case where the VM is running on the same machine as the debugger use `\\.\` rather than `\\VMHost\`

[Setting Up Kernel-Mode Debugging of a Virtual Machine Manually](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff538143%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) may also be helpful in general.